# Windows 7 Explorer - Activate mouse focus to be able to scroll in tree and file view?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, focus, scrolling, mouse-wheel

I'd like to be able to scroll in the tree view without having to click in it. Is there a way to do this?
I have once used a tool that generally gives focus to the window underneath the mouse cursor, but this caused some other glitches so I would like to achieve this without an extra tool.
I also think that there are programs that embed the Windows Explorer and offer more features, including the behaviour I would like to have. But maybe a registry value change is all that is needed?

Comment: Here are three tools in the like that I mentioned:
http://ehiti.de/katmouse/
http://vb.mvps.org/tools/Wheeler/
http://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wizmouse-makes-your-mouse-wheel-work-on-the-window-under-the-mouse/

Comment: KatMouse works for me very well on Win7 x64, for the same purpose.

Answer (score 11):

I have installed [WizMouse](http://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wizmouse-makes-your-mouse-wheel-work-on-the-window-under-the-mouse/) which allows scrolling in background/non-focus windows (as per standard Mac behaviour) which should solve the issue - and in my opinion should be default mouse behaviour anyway :)

To be clear, it doesn't need to grab the focus and bring the window to the front, just allows you to scroll in the background.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 Control panel > "Ease of Access Centre" > "Make the mouse easier to use" there is an option to grab focus on hover, however, this will affect all windows, not just explorer.

Comment: +1 because I did not know about this. But will it work as good as WizMouse ?

Comment: Just tried it out. Well the problem is it brings the whole Windows to the front which is not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

[KatMouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/) works perfectly, rather than " Control panel > Ease of Access Centre > Make the mouse easier to use" which only focus the window you point, and don't make any scroll possibility at all in Explorer

Comment: Can you provide more information on KatMouse. Where do you get it from? how much does it cost (if anything)? Also please make it clear if you are affiliated with the product.

Comment: http://ehiti.de/katmouse/ seems to be the link and its mentioned on lifehacker. Also, not updated since 07.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>F6</kbd> to move focus between the different sections of the current window, and I think Windows Explorer also accepts <kbd>Tab</kbd> for much the same function. This will probably require more than a single press though.

You might also want to have a look at the [Windows 7 Keyboard Shortcut List](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts), as that might be useful.
Note that it does not provide a shortcut to give focus to the folder tree, so we can probably assume that there isn't one built in.

Comment: Thanks, TAB works unless you're dragging a file over to the tree..

Comment: @none In case yu're not aware; when you're dragging a file you can hold to at the top or bottom of the folder list to make the list scroll. It's no where near as fast as using the wheel though...

Answer (score 0):

For scrolling between panes (not between active/inactive windows) just use this app called [FlashWheel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flashwheel/). Has no UI, runs as a hidden app. To close it, terminate it from Task Manager.   This fixes what you want and ONLY that, no other settings or boxes to tick.